# PHP not parsing with LAMP on Debian 7

Tags: php, apache, debian, lamp

Okay, I've looked around for the answer to this here, & on various forums, but my experience is a little different than what I'm seeing. My server is remote, and I have a PHPINFO file in my /var/www/ directory, however, its just showing a blank page, & the PHP code is all that shows in the page source.

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
?>
```

I'm using PHP5 & Apache2.
I'm not sure what information to provide so if any more is needed, just let me know!

Comment: There's far too many dupes of this on the site: a) Apache is misconfigured and does nod have mod_php loaded b) You've used the wrong filename (e.g. .html) and Apache is treating the file like plaintext/html.

Comment: Apache is a fresh install. The file is info.php. 

I do see similar errors, but none in which it shows the code like this, hence why I posted. I don't mean to spam, but if its not the same issue, I'm not going to apply recommended troubleshooting steps.

Comment: did you check if mod_php is being loaded into apache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalled Apache2 then MySQL, then PHP5. This resolved the issue.